# `rake spec` fails with no error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

- OS X Mavericks
- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rails 2.3.18
- Rspec 1.3.2
- Rspec-rails 1.3.4

Output of `rake spec`

```
$ rake spec
(in /Users/timosand/Dropbox/Development/epassi)
Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation.
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/annotate_models/tasks, vendor/plugins/barcode_generator/tasks, vendor/plugins/crypted_authentication/tasks, vendor/plugins/oauth-plugin/tasks, vendor/plugins/tarantula/tasks, and vendor/plugins/ym4r_gm/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/carrierwave-0.4.10/lib/carrierwave.rb:84)
/Users/timosand/Dropbox/Development/epassi/config/initializers/oauth_consumers.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/Users/timosand/Dropbox/Development/epassi/lib/spreadsheet/format.rb:21: warning: already initialized constant COLORS
```

I have 45 spec files

```
$ find spec -name '*_spec.rb' | wc -l  
45
```

I've added `p __FILE_` to each spec and every filename gets printed. Still the actual tests are not run.

Any advice on how to solve this?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/deiga/370b61518d63332badcd) is my `spec_helper.rb` and one controller spec as an example

Comment: what do your tests look like? Do you actually have any?

Comment: post please rails version, `spec_helper.rb` and check that you have specs in spec folder (yes maybe there no tests :) ) and files have names like `some_file_spec.rb`

Comment: the rails version is 2.3.18, from the backtrace.

Comment: Yes, I really do have tests. I added the requested information to the post

Comment: Any insights to this would be great...